# Docker will not attach to an image

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile, fig

I have a fig.yml file that I am using to set up my docker containers. I run this by typing ./fig up Then it outputs the following:

```
Recreating docker_memcache_1...
Recreating docker_sphinx_1...
Recreating docker_percona_1...
Recreating docker_php_1...
Recreating docker_sa_1...
Attaching to docker_memcache_1, docker_percona_1, docker_php_1
```

So once that is done everything is up and running. My issue is that for some reason it is not attaching to the nginx container I have set up. The docker ps command outputs the following:

```
9bb0c647338e        php:latest          "/usr/sbin/php-fpm -   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        9000/tcp            docker_php_1        
9f74789bdb15        percona:latest      "mysqld"               3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            docker_percona_1    
b848d3442bdf        memcached:latest    "/bin/sh -c memcache   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        11211/tcp           docker_memcache_1
```

So the memcache image, the php image, and the percona image all are good to go, however there is no nginx docker image like there should be.

Below is how I have my fig.yml file set up, which is basically the file that launches everything. Does anyone have any ideas on what may be happening? Just to note i do have the daemon set to off so it should not be quitting automatically.

fig.yml File here :

```
sa:
  image: nginx
  links:
    - php:php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./svn (path here)
    - ./cert:/(path here)
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
memcache:
  image: memcached
  hostname: memcached.docker
sphinx:
  image: sphinx
  hostname: sphinx.docker
percona:
  image: percona
  hostname: percona.docker
php:
  image: php
  hostname: php.docker
  links:  
    - memcache:memcache.docker
    - sphinx:sphinx.docker
    - percona:percona.docker
```

Also thought I would include my nginx Dockerfile in case there is something in there im missing Any help is greatly appreciated

Nginx Dockerfile

```
From centos:6.6
RUN yum -y install http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install nginx && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 80 443
COPY sa.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY base /etc/nginx/base/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `docker ps -a` to show all containers, not just running containers. You'll see `docker_sa_1` listed as a stopped container. This is because it crashed immediately on start-up. Unfortunately, fig doesn't show the logs for you (or shut down the stack automatically) when this happens.

Run `docker logs docker_sa_1` to see the output. Hopefully, there will be a nice Nginx error message for you. If you can't find anything, then remove the `sa` entry from your `fig.yml`, do a `fig up` to get everything else started, then run

```
docker run -it --link=docker_php_1:php-fpm -v $PWD/svn:(?) -v $PWD/cert:(?) -p 8080:80 nginx
```

(You'll need to fill in the `?`s with the path bits you left out) This is equivalent to what Fig's doing, except we're starting the container interactive with an attached tty instead of attaching later. If you *still* can't get any error messages, run

```
docker run -it --link=docker_php_1:php-fpm -v $PWD/svn:(?) -v $PWD/cert:(?) -p 8080:80 nginx /bin/bash
```

to get a live shell on the container. Then try starting Nginx yourself and dig for log files after it crashes.

Comment: This worked just as you said. The nginx had exited due to it not liking the path name for the SSL certificate. Thank you for the help